# setOnKeyListner not working for EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, keylistener

Here i have a fragment and it contains an edit text I want to hide the soft keyboard on Enter Key Press.

I tried this. but it seems my onKey Method is not called. i have checked through `Log`

```
edTxtUserText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI);

    edTxtUserText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edTxtUserText.getWindowToken(),
                        0);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

- whats wrong in my code.

also here is my XML of editText

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edTxtPreview"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtText"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
                android:ems="10"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                android:inputType="textCapWords|text"
                android:lines="1"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:text="Your Text Here"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" >
            </EditText>
```

also I have set OnClickListner on this editText Also. as

```
edTxtUserText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            edTxtUserText.requestFocus();
            edTxtUserText.selectAll();
            ((InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                    Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(
                    InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }
    });
```

Comment: On which view click you want to hide softkeyboard ? You are trying to hide on Edittext here but i think for the android keyboard it provides a enter key and to hide the keyboard you need to set the EditText property `android:singleLine="true"` .

Comment: i want to hide the softkeyboard on EnterKey press of the EditText's keyboard

Comment: You can set the `android:singleLine="true"` in your layout file for the `EditText` and try out . It will automatically hide the softkeyboard on pressing of the enter key of the keyboard.

Comment: i have tried this. its focusing the next view (i.e tab in my case) down there while pressing the Enter key

Comment: I know this is old but, I have found using flagNoExtractUi stops the KeyListener, looking for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use code and successfully able to close the keyboard while pressing `done` key but I just replace below line of code:

Try:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                        getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                           InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Instead:

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edTxtUserText.getWindowToken(),
                        0);
```

Note: tested in emulator.

Comment: I m using fragments hence I have to use getActivity().getSystemService instead of getSystemService() only

Comment: i have tried this. its focusing the next view (i.e tab in my case) down there while pressing the Enter key

Answer (score 0):

you can try using following code

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                //Do Operations here
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working your way i.e using onKeyListener. Use keycode instead of getAction()
Just use

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Log.d("Neha", "in if condition ");
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edTxtUserText.getWindowToken(),
                            0);
                    return true;
                }
```